# HTML/CSS confusion

Tags: html, css

Currently studying computer science, but I've really only dealt with c++ & java. Currently trying to learn html & css, which is obviously not as difficult as having to write the code for a binary search tree which will balance itself after inserting data.

ANYWAYS!! I'm stuck! I dont understand why the .h css style in the following code isn't working on the contents of the div box!! Any help would be great.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type=“text/css”>
.h {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;  
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class=“h”>Hello World</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is obviously a very simple code of block, but the Hello World doesn't turn red. Would love to know what I am doing wrong.

THANK YOU!

P.S. I have tried checking the output on http://www.littlewebhut.com/html/
and nothing :(

Comment: The quote marks in your `style` and `div` tags are "smart-quotes" that don't match, not real quotes, blame your editor.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Another user pointed out the same! The smallest of issues always end up being the most difficult to figure out haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong set of quotes for the class value.

“h” is different from "h"

This likely happened because of your text editor converting the plain quotes like " to the more fancy ones “ and ”

So to fix it, use:

```
<div class="h">Hello World</div>
```

The same goes for `type=“text/css”` but you don't need to specify this at all; only having `<style>` will suffice since CSS is the standard for stylesheets.

Make sure to disable smart quotes from your text editor!

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!! That is exactly what was wrong! Thank you so much. I had been looking over this trying to understand why it wasn't working. Great eye! :) It truly always ends up being the simplest of issues.

Answer (score -1):

CSS, while simple in appearance, can challenge one's mind. I see that your issue boiled down to unicode or smart quotes. Just an FYI, quotes are actually not necessary on classes applied to HTML elements.

```css
.h {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class=h>Hello World</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer is using smart quotes `“h”` for the class value. Plain quotes should be used `"h"`.

Comment: This actually helped tremendously as well!! Thank you! I will rid my html div classes of quotes altogether to simplify!